# How does reducer works when state = initialState?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

A sample code from an online course:

```
import * as PlayerActionTypes from '../actiontypes/player';

const initialState = [
      {
        name: 'Jim Hoskins',
        score: 31,
      },
      {
        name: 'Andrew Chalkley',
        score: 20,
      },
      {
        name: 'Alena Holligan',
        score: 50,
      },
    ];

export default function Player(state=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'PlayerActionTypes.ADD_PLAYER':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          name: action.name,
          score: 0,
        }
      ];

      case PlayerActionTypes.REMOVE_PLAYER:
        return [
          ...state.slice(0, action.index),
          ...state.slice(action.index+1),
        ]
  }
}
```

As the initialState is immutable(always the same), then the state is the same. So, let's say, if I first add an new player, a total of four players now. If then I want to remove the fourth player (whose index is 3 in the array), but how does it work?

```
case PlayerActionTypes.REMOVE_PLAYER:
            return [
              ...state.slice(0, action.index),
              ...state.slice(action.index+1),
            ]
```

There is no index = 3 in the 'state' (only three players).

I don't understand. Please provide some help on my confusion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you say there is no index=3 in state? (assuming you've added one before deleting)

Comment: @deezg Because from 'state=initialState' (the first argument in the function), as 'initialState' is always the same(only three players defined initially), how 'state' change> which is my confusion. I don't understand this part.

Comment: ok, now i see where the confusion comes from. check if my answer helps understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function Player(state=initialState, action) {
```

whenever action is dispatched, this function gets called with 2 parameters:

1. state (which is current app state)
2. action

based on those 2, this function returns new app state (which will be used as parameter in next call to this function with new action)

now, for the very first run, when app state is still null, the parameter `state` will be set to `initialState`. for every next run, since state will no longer be null, your `state` parameter will be whatever the current app state is.

check ES6 function default parameters.